# reportviewer bar chart, bar width incorrect

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, report-builder2.0

I have a problem with a report that is build using report builder 2.0, on a sql2008 database (latest service pack installed), reporting services Version 10.0.5500.0.

The problem is that the bars are wider then they should be. Each bar should be as width as 1 hour.

The x-axis is configured with the interval set to `hour` and an interval value of `1` the min-value of `=TimeSerial(0,0,0)` and max-value of `=TimeSerial(23,59,0)`. The series has a `CategoryField` set to the `[hour]`, a column of type `time` with the time of an hour (Example `08:00:00.0000000`).

[image: Example of the problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is in the properties grid under General--> Custom Attributes --> PointWidth
You have to select the series first.
If you can't see the properties grid you need to enable it from the ribbon. View, check the box next to properties.

Numbers less than 1 will give gaps between the bars, number greater than 1 will cause the bars to overlap.

It's more of a relative width setting than abosolutely related to your Hour interval, but you can tweak it so its right. 
Personally I would suggest you have it slightly less than an hour because they look better with gaps.

[barchart1.png](http://davoscollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/barchart1.png)

You should also set the labels on the horizontal axis to be vertical and then rotate them so it looks a bit better.